# Model Manager queryset not filtering

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a proxy model whose queryset is a subset of its parent. However, when I call it, the parent's objects are returned instead.

**[Model Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets)**:

```
class NewRequestsManager(models.Manager):        
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(NewRequestsManager, self).get_queryset().filter(is_scoped=0)
```

**Proxy Model**:

```
class NewRequests(Engagement):
    objects = NewRequestsManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        app_label = 'myapp'
        verbose_name = 'New Request'
```

**View**:

```
def list(request):
    new_requests = NewRequests.objects.all()
    c = RequestContext(request, {
            'cl': new_requests,
    })
    t = loader.get_template('queue.html')
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Any help is much appreciated.  I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably just a typo: `get_queryset` should be `get_query_set`, so you aren't overriding anything.

```
class NewRequestsManager(models.Manager):        
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(NewRequestsManager, self).get_query_set().filter(is_scoped=0)
```

Comment: Thanks Ric.  There's nothing like banging your head for a typo LOL.

Answer (score 7):

Not a typo: [dev documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets) uses get_queryset whereas [1.5 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets) uses get_query_set I suppose there has been a recent change in dev version.

Comment: Wow downgraded my django to get other things working and have been banging my head on this one ><.